# Inserting a "," in a particular position of a text

Tags: regex, awk, sed

(I put a exact text and command I executed so would be looking a bit messy.)

I have a .TXT file looking like

```
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

And outcome I am looking for would be like

```
11111111111111,1111111,11,1,111,1111111111111,1,11111111,1111111111111111,111,111
11111111111111,1111111,11,1,111,1111111111111,1,11111111,1111111111111111,111,111
```

Command I have tried is

```
sed -i 's/\(.\{14\}\)\(.\{7\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{1\}\)\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{13\}\)\(.\{1\}\)\(.\{8\}\)\(.\{16\}\)\(.\{3\}\)/\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7,\8,\9,\10,/' SOME.TXT
```

And outcome I have got was

```
11111111111111,1111111,11,1,111,1111111111111,1,11111111,1111111111111111,1111111111111110,111
11111111111111,1111111,11,1,111,1111111111111,1,11111111,1111111111111111,1111111111111110,111
```

I have literally no idea why these 0s suddenly popped out and ' , ' doesn't appear in the position where I command even though it worked half way.

Is this a bug or something in sed command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is printing `0` in output because `sed` capture groups and their back-references can be up to 9 only and `\10` is interpreted as `\1` followed by literal `0`.

You can solve it easily using [`FIELDWIDTHS` feature of `gnu-awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

```
awk -v OFS=, 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "14 7 2 1 3 13 1 8 16 3 *" } {$1 = $1} 1' file
```

```
11111111111111,1111111,11,1,111,1111111111111,1,11111111,1111111111111111,111,111
11111111111111,1111111,11,1,111,1111111111111,1,11111111,1111111111111111,111,111
```

---

Just for academic exercise, here is a working `sed` to solve this using 2 substitutions:

```
sed -E 's/(.{14})(.{7})(.{2})(.)(.{3})(.{13})(.)(.{8})(.+)/\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7,\8,\9/; s/(.+,.{16})(.{3})(.*)/\1,\2,\3/' file
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  
I am not really familiar with awk command yet so I am gonna try that later also but the second suggestion worked perfectly for me!

Comment: @gggert use the awk solution. Whether you're more familiar with sed or not surely you can see how much simpler the awk solution is.

Comment: nice answer and useful GNU awk feature.

Answer (score 6):

sed can't reference capture groups > 9, Perl can:

```
perl -i -pe  's/(.{14})(.{7})(.{2})(.)(.{3})(.{13})(.)(.{8})(.{16})(.{3})/$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,/' SOME.TXT
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to use `sed`, you can do something like:

```sh
sed 's/./&,/68;s/./&,/65;s/./&,/49;s/./&,/41;s/./&,/40;s/./&,/27;s/./&,/24;s/./&,/23;s/./&,/21;s/./&,/14' test.txt
11111111111111,1111111,11,1,111,1111111111111,1,11111111,1111111111111111,111,111
11111111111111,1111111,11,1,111,1111111111111,1,11111111,1111111111111111,111,111
```